# How to give link from button in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a button using

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg ">Register</button>
```

How could I give a link to another page when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a anchor instead, and you can still style it as a button..

```
<a href="/page.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Register</a>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/99320